# Installing smarty plugin on eclipse oxygen

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, smarty

I am trying to install the smarty feature in eclipse oxigen. I used

> Help -> Install New Software

Here I entered

> Work with: http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org

Under `Text Editors / Productivity Tools` I selected `Smarty feature` and then installed.

Now when I try to open a `.tpl` file in eclipse it tells me that the `Editor could not be initialized.`

Am I missing something obvious to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

As the homepage of the PDT Extension group says:

> This updatesite hosts SNAPSHOT versions. The stable updatesite available here: p2.pdt-extensions.org/.

So if you install the editor from http://p2.pdt-extensions.org it should work.

Comment: that didn't fix it I'm afraid